# How to use user input numbers in Edit control box to some control program coded behind a button?

Tags: mfc

I'm trying to take user input in the edit control box and use a button to sort those numbers and display it onto other edit control box. Can't figure out how to accept input into edit control and use them in button sorting functionality.

`arr.GetData();` to get array variables in sorting algorithm input and `m_edit.GetWindowText();` for edit control box but this doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: `m_edit.GetWindowText()` looks good, but if you want an answer, you need to provide more code, otherwise any answer will be based on guesswork. For example we have no idea what `arr` is.

Comment: basically i'm trying to take input numbers from user in edit control box and sort the numbers using a button. so the sorting algorithm written inside the button function needs the user input from the edit control box. that's what i wanted to know to to do. maybe using Clist or Carray collection but how if you can shed some light. thankyou

Comment: You need to show more code. Otherwise it's hard to help.